# Simultaneous equation

Tags: calculus

Solve that

$x-y=a  ,  2x^2+y^2=9$ and let solution set $(x,y) = (\alpha,\beta)$

Find the maximum value of $|\alpha + \beta|$

where $a$ is a real number

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x-y=a \implies x = y+a$. Plug this into your second equation to find the solution set.

Comment: So I try it and that absolute value has form $\frac {-a \pm \sqrt{27-a^2}}3$. Next what should I do? and I'm sorry I omitted that we can't use differentiation

Comment: @user128766 Those are not the solutions. See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28y%2Ba%29%5E2%2By%5E2-9%3D0). $y=\frac{-2a\pm \sqrt{27-2a^2}}{3}$

Comment: There should be only 2 solutions. Manual calculation of $|\alpha+\beta|$ should reveal which one is maximal.

Comment: So what is the maximum value? It must be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.